# Error at the line 4033: ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, webmin, virtualmin

Trying to upload MySQL backup WordPress database in Webmin/Virtualmin server with `bigdum.php`

```
Error at the line 4033: ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Query: --
--
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
`ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`post_author` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
`comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
`ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
`post_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`post_parent` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
`post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

MySQL: Invalid default value for 'post_date'
```

How can i solve this issue?
Can anyone help please